# How to upload/download to/from Artifactory using jfrog CLI tool in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, artifactory, jfrog-cli

So I'm having some issues to get the jf CLI tool up and running under Windows using PowerShell. I've opted for the install mechanism of installing the jf CLI tool via PowerShell command.
I had quite a bit of trouble configuring a server in the first place. Anyway, I solved it by exporting my configuration on Linux and importing it in PowerShell.

My problem is whatever I do, I receive a RemoteException. When I try to upload or download a file, for example by using this command:
`jf rt u my-source-folder/ my-rt-repository/`, I first receive a RemoteException followed by this:

```
{
  "status": "success"
  "totals": {
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 0
  }
}
```

I assume I do something wrong, by using the Linux syntax (works on Linux), but I honestly don't know where to get a reference with PowerShell commands, since the JFrog website is a load of garbage.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You mentioned that you received Remote Exception. Does "jf rt ping" work for you? You can  use this command to verify that there's connectivity between your machine and Artifactory.

Comment: @EyalBenMoshe It returns OK

Comment: After some playing around with it, turns out that I had errors in both my upload and download commands, which I have fixed now. So it actually does work, however I'm still getting these annoying RemoteExceptions for some reason.

Comment: Will you be able to edit your question, and share the exact Remote Exception messages that you're getting?